# Uninstalling Java 6 and Reinstalling Java 7 using Powershell

Tags: java, powershell, installation, uninstallation

I am using the following Powershell script. The first half (uninstall) works flawlessly. The second half (install) only works if I allow user input. Can anyone provide some assistance? Here is the script: (sorry for poor formatting)

```
#uninstall
$java = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product | where { $_.Name -like "*Java*"}
$msiexec = "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe";
$msiexecargs = '/x "$($app.IdentifyingNumber)" /qn /norestart'

if ($java -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($app in $java)
    {
        write-host $app.LocalPackage
        write-host $app.IdentifyingNumber
        C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /x $($app.IdentifyingNumber) /qn"
        Start-Process -FilePath $msiexec -Arg $msiexecargs -Wait -Passthru
        [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($msiexec, $msiexecargs);
    }
}
if ($java -ne $null)
{
    foreach ($app in $java)

{
        write-host $app.LocalPackage
        write-host $app.IdentifyingNumber

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c 

"C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe /x $($app.IdentifyingNumber) /qn"

        Start-Process -FilePath $msiexec -Arg $msiexecargs -Wait -Passthru
        [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($msiexec, $msiexecargs);
    }
}

function Get-ScriptDirectory{
    $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value

try {
        Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path -ea 0
    }

catch {
    Write-Warning 'You need to call this function from within a saved script.'
    }
}

function Get-Architecture{
    return $(gwmi win32_operatingsystem).OSArchitecture
}


$Path = Get-ScriptDirectory

#Close all instances of IE, Firefox, & Chrome
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -match "iexplore"} | Stop-Process -Force
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -match "chrome"} | Stop-Process -Force
Get-Process | where {$_.ProcessName -match "firefox"} | Stop-Process -Force

#Install
Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i "C:\temp\jre1.7.0_17.msi" ""/log "c:\temp\javainst.log " -Credential $cred -wait

#Also Install the 64-bit JRE if on a 64 workstation

if(Get-Architecture -match "64")
{
    $cred = Get-Credential
    Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i "C:\temp\jre1.7.0_17 (x64).msi" ""/log c:\temp\javainst.log " -Credential $cred -wait
}

#Import reg keys to disable auto updating
reg import "C:\temp\JavaUpdate.reg"{ 
    }
```

Comment: For formatting, get rid of all the tick marks, and simply indent the code 4 spaces, and it will automatically be formatted as code.

Comment: What does "allow user input" mean? Do they need to click "next" in the wizard? You're missing a silent argument like ` /qn` in your install code. Also, why use `msiexec` to install when Java has it's own silent trigger in the exe-file `jre..blah.blah.exe /s` Read more: http://java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
#uninstall everything Java
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_product | ? {$_.Name -like "*Java*"} | % {msiexec /x "$($_.IdentifyingNumber)" /qn | Out-Null}
#The Out-Null waits for the command to finish

#If you have made a Java MSI use this
msiexec /i $pathtomsi /qn

#If you only have the exe you'll need to look up the Command Line Interface (CLI) for Java
$cmd = "$pathtoexe /s"
cmd /c $cmd
```

As for your script change the #Install line to:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'msiexec.exe' -ArgumentList '/i "C:\temp\jre1.7.0_17.msi" /log "c:\temp\javainst.log" /qn' -Credential $cred -wait
```

[Best Practice use mostly single quotes](http://www.windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-with-a-purpose-blog-36/windows-powershell/powershell-part-7-139515)

Comment: I have tried via MSI and .exe - can anyone explain to me why this works:  Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i `"C:\temp\jre1.7.0_17.msi`"" -Credential $cred -wait

But this doesn't: Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList "/i `"C:\temp\jre1.7.0_17.msi`" ""`/qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress JAVAUPDATE=0 WEBSTARTICON=0 SYSTRAY=0`" ""/log c:\temp\javainst.log" -Credential $cred -wait

Comment: You might be better off writing another script that changes the properties of the Java installation after it install. When you open up a DOS window and run the command `msiexec /i "C:\jre17.msi" /qn REBOOT=ReallySuppress JAVAUPDATE=0 ...` does that work? Oracle doesn't give too much documentation with the MSI. Do they even supply an MSI?